# Ajax request is not connecting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[image]

```
$("#email").keyup(function() {
              var vall = $(this).val();

              if(vall == "") {
                  $("#emailerror").html("Email should not be empty");
                  email = "";
              } 
               else {
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "post",
                      url: "script.php",
                      data: "email=" +vall,
                      success: function(msg) {
                         $("#emailerror").html(msg); 
                      }
                  });
              }
          });

         <?php
      include 'includes/db.php';

      if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          echo $email;
      }
      ?>
```

These are my two different files one is ajax request and another is php script,I am trying to to email validation via ajax whether it is already present in database but there is some kind of error in console which is in screenshot below can any suggest me what is the problem

[image]

Comment: is "script.php" in the same folder as "index.html"?

Comment: edited my question with the directories

Comment: Can you open `script.php` via your browser? Like http://localhost:64065/script.php.

Comment: I can't replicate this on my side, I have `index.html` (containing the JavaScript AJAX) that is posting to `script.php` which is in the same directory as `index.html` and it works.

Comment: i have to change my jquery version my version is 1.1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the URL of the `script.php` file Try it like this. First you should have a BASE_URL or SITE_URL like

```
define('SITE_URL', 'http://www.example.com');
```

Then in jQuery append to this URL so it makes the complete path like

```
$("#email").keyup(function() {
              var vall = $(this).val();

              if(vall == "") {
                  $("#emailerror").html("Email should not be empty");
                  email = "";
              } 
               else {
                  $.ajax({
                      type: "post",
                      url: "<?php echo SITE_URL;?>/script.php",
                      data: "email=" +vall,
                      success: function(msg) {
                         $("#emailerror").html(msg); 
                      }
                  });
              }
          });
```

This will call the script.php file (Adjust the path to `script.php` file path based on your setup.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like below.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "script.php",
 data: {email: vall},
 success: function(msg) {
   $("#emailerror").html(msg); 
 }
```

Comment: While passing an object to `data` instead of generating the encoded data yourself by mashing strings together is best practise … it isn't going to solve the problem of `script.php` being a URL to a 404 error.